# Possible to modify the width of a button?

Tags: scripting

I am talking about the animation control buttons on the Timeline panel. In short, I would like to make the buttons wider, either by setting a horizontal padding value or by specifying width. If possible, with an add-on script or if that is not possible, by modifying the scripts in the "scripts" directory of Blender.

The buttons seem to be added in "space_time.py" line 41 to 62, like

```
    row.operator("screen.frame_jump", text="", icon='REW').end = False
```

but how to change the looks? Is it even possible to change the width? I am not sure because all buttons in Blender seems have no width (just the width of the text or filling the parent UI).

Comment: Somewhat dependant on where it is in UI it is very hard to set an absolute width on a UI element. For relative Can scale the width and height of UI via their `scale_x` and `scale_y` attribute to produce something like https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161983/operator-tooltip-from-layout-text

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks. At first I tried to set `scale_x` to the result of `operator()`, but that did not work. Then I added `row.scale_x = 2` before the buttons were added, then all the buttons were scaled. The only problem is that the buttons are not centred on the toolbar but a little bit skewed the left, and I did that by modifying the `space_time.py`. Is it possible with an add-on?